# Azure API Management Conditional outbound headers

Tags: azure, cors, azure-api-management

I'm using API Management to set outbound headers which was sufficient till now with a single domain using this policy block

```
    <outbound>
        <base />
        <set-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" exists-action="override">
            <value>https://example.com</value>
        </set-header>
    </outbound>
```

However I now need to manage multiple domains for Access-Control-Allow-Origin and based on an approved list of domains. I have tried to use a conditional block but this does not work.

```
    <outbound>
        <base />
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Request.OriginalUrl.Host ==  "example.com")">
                <return-response>
                    <set-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" exists-action="override">
                        <value>https://example.com</value>
                    </set-header>
                </return-response>
            </when>
            <when condition="@(context.Request.OriginalUrl.Host ==  "example1.com")">
                <return-response>
                    <set-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" exists-action="override">
                        <value>https://example1.com</value>
                    </set-header>
                </return-response>
            </when>
            <otherwise />
        </choose>
    </outbound>
```

We have an increasing list of domains which need to be handled to send a response back to the client with the header if domain from the request matches the list. Is there a better way to handle this and how can I make this work?

Comment: Any particular reason why you can't use APIM's CORS policy?

Answer (score -1):

The [CORS Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-cross-domain-policies#CORS) allows listing multiple allowed origins and takes care of the response headers based on the request.